# How do you print a function from user input?

Tags: python, function

I am still new to python, so pardon me if this question seems stupid. I need   my code to work on user input. I was expecting to be prompted for user input to complete the code but when I run the code, I get a blank terminal, no errors or extra information. 
This is the code:

```
def minutes_to_hours(name):
    minutes = input("Insert minutes here: ")
    hours = minutes / 60
    return hours
    print(hours)
```

This is the output:

```
Adwoks-MacBook-Pro:Python Adwok$ python3 myfunction.py
```

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: Also the `print` statement is after the return statement so it is never executed. Also why take a `name` parameter that is never used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You have given the function definition, but not really calling the function. Function declaration tells python (interpreter) what the piece of code does, function call requests the execution of the piece of code. So, at the end of the function definition, you should add `minutes_to_hours(name)`.

**2.** Your code is not correct. Make a clear abstract definition of your function first. From what you've coded, it appears you were not quite sure what the function should do- should it return the number of hours, or should it print the number of hours? Also, note that either way the entire program (whatever you have written, function+everything else) seems to be supposed to print the number of hours, given number of minutes. You can achieve it by implementing your function in any of the two ways.

If function should return the number of hours, then the code should look like as follows, with the errors rectified:

```
def minutes_to_hours():
# input returns string, you should explicitly cast it to int/float
    minutes = int(input("Insert minutes here: "))
    hours = minutes / 60
    return hours

hours = minutes_to_hours()
print(hours)
```

Note that no parameters need to be passed to the function to get the hours from minutes if you're taking input from the user within the function itself.

Also, once the `return()` statement is executed, the control comes back to the line from where function call had been made. So, in your code, `print()` statement never will get executed as it comes after `return()`.

However, if you'd like to print number of hours, and not return it, then the code should look like:

```
def minutes_to_hours():
    # input returns string, you should explicitly cast it to int/float
        minutes = int(input("Insert minutes here: "))
        hours = minutes / 60
        print(hours)

    minutes_to_hours()
```

Note that since no return is being made from the function, I do not have any assignment operator preceding the function call (I do not have any return value to store in a variable, so pointless to do something like `hours = minutes_to_hours`, hours in this case will have `None` though).

Still if you want your function to print as well as return the value of `hours`, then you should do it in the following order:

```
print(hours)
return(hours)
```

But this is not really required if your *program (function + rest of the code)* is supposed to print the number of hours, which can implemented by doing it in one of the ways. Why do both, then? You'll make your computer work more on something that can be done in a better, optimized way.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function, you need to call the function using `result = minutes_to_hours(name)` .

Also, it will not print out `hours` because it is after the return statement. These should be the other way round.

Note: you can remove the parameter `name` from the function as you do not use it in the function.

Comment: I did not notice that 'name', my code kept giving errors. But that's now cleared up. So can you explain to me why it couldn't just ignore it if it has no purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this. A function is not required in this situation.

```
minutes = input("Insert minutes here: ")
hours = float(minutes) / 60
print(hours)
```

Comment: I was using the function because I could use it elsewhere without having to type that full code block before it. But your method works too.

Answer (score 0):

As  Aidan Rosswood  stated, you are only defining function. And also the function do not seem working, re-visit as,

```
def minutes_to_hours():
  minutes = input("Insert minutes here: ")
  hours = minutes / 60
  print(hours)    
  return hours
```

Now, call the function as you require as,

```
minutes_to_hours()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function but haven't called it. Try this

```
def minutes_to_hours(min):
    hours = min / 60
    return hours

minutes = float(input("Insert minutes here: "))
hours = minutes_to_hours(minutes)
print(hours)
```

You can also use one-liner instead.

```
print(float(input('Insert minutes here: ')) / 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def minutes_to_hours():
    minutes = input("Insert minutes here: ")
    minutes1 = int(minutes)
    hours = minutes1 / 60
    print(hours)

minutes_to_hours()
```

remove name and call the function